# Fluid simulation not baking when an obstacle is present

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been messing around with this for hours now. When I have a fluid domain and a fluid object, it bakes just fine. As soon as I add an obstacle though, nothing happens when I bake. I've looked at several youtube tutorials and forum answers, but no one seems to be having this problem.
I have no settings changed other than slip and resolution.
I've heard that the fluid sim is pretty glitchy. Is that just the case here? The weird thing is, I've done this exact thing before and it worked perfectly fine. Now for some reason it's just not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Oh, I'm just trying to make a wine glass with fluid in it.

Comment: Are they set to volume or shell.

Comment: I usually have it set to both, but i didn't think that would cause the domain to not bake.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out. Messing with the Volume Initialization (Volume, Shell, or Both) seemed to fix the baking issue. Thank you Yohello 1 for the response!
I had the obstacle set to both, which wasn't working. Switched it to shell and it worked fine. Pretty sure volume worked as well, just not both.
Hope this helps others too.